# Is it a bad idea to insert records that don't already exist like this?

Tags: mysql

For large databases, is it OK to use a select like this to avoid inserting duplicates? Does mysql optimize the WHERE NOT clause some how or is it a bad idea to do this. Lets say tableA has 5 million records.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
(SELECT DISTINCT tableB.a as colA, tableB.b as colB, tableB.c as colC
 FROM tableB
 WHERE NOT tableB.colA IN 
 (SELECT colA FROM tableA)
)
```

Comment: short answer - yes!

Comment: This is a bad idea and a poor understanding of RDBMS normalisation.  Firstly, you will face race condition. Secondly, you are not making use of database duplicates key check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want no duplicates in `colA`, then the "right" way is to let the database do the work.  So:

```
create unique index unq_tableA_colA on tableA(colA);
```

Then, you can run the query, arranging to ignore any duplication errors:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
    SELECT DISTINCT tableB.a as colA, tableB.b as colB, tableB.c as colC
    FROM tableB
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colA = VALUES(colA);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it eliminates concern about race conditions.  Two inserts happening "at the same time" could insert the same value "A" into the table.  However, when the database is guaranteeing the integrity of the data, this cannot happen.

And, because the uniqueness guarantee uses an index, it does not incur that much additional overhead (and much less than your version if it doesn't have an index on the column).

Answer (score 0):

I would change the last subquery part to a `JOIN` query like

```
INSERT INTO tableA (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT DISTINCT tableB.a as colA, tableB.b as colB, tableB.c as colC
 FROM tableB JOIN tableA ON tableB.colA <> tableA.colA;
```